# Can't load libcef symbols in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, symbols, chromium

I'm working with libcef right now, and I can't get the .pdb file to load while I'm debugging.

I'm using the version 3.1180.719 precompiled binary from here: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/downloads/detail?name=cef_binary_3.1180.719_windows.zip&can=2&q=

And I'm trying to load the 3.1180.719 symbols from the .pdb file I downloaded from here: http://www.magpcss.net/cef_symbols/

When I hit a breakpoint with some libcef calls in the stack I try to load symbols from this .pdb file (kept in the same directory as libcef.dll and libcef.lib, different directory from my project). It says "**A matching symbol file was not found in this folder**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .pdb file only works with Release versions of CEF. I was trying to use it on the debug .dll.

You can find the Debug CEF symbols (.pdb files) here: http://www.magpcss.net/cef_symbols/